# How to store data in Firestore (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an iOS app using Cloud Firestore and have problems with updating the data. My goal is to add urls to a dictionary one by one, but all I get is rewritten one value. How should I use setData and updateData? Tried it different ways

```
storageRef.child("users/" + currentUser.value!.documentID + "/" + faceRef.documentID + ".jpg")
          .putData(data!).observe(.success) { (snapshot) in

        guard let downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString else { return }
        let db = self.fsReference.document(self.currentUser.value!.documentID)
        var dict = ["faces": ["": ""]]
        dict["faces"] = ["newvalue\(downloadURL.hashValue)": downloadURL]

        db.updateData(dict)
        completion?()
```

Here's what I tried. Any advice would be nice, thanks in advance!

UPD: Tried to move my dictionary to subcollection, but after `.collection("newCollection").document("newdocument")` collection does not appear. What might be the problem?

Comment: Hi Max. When you do an update like this, you will endeed "replace" the object. A solution could be to store the urls in a sub collection?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Currently there are problems with subcollections, they are doesn't appear when I do something like `.collection("newcollection").document("newDocument")` and when I put data, nothing happens to the database. What do you thing might be the problem?

Comment: Are you using the full path? If you were to save it on the users document, should look like this: `users/${currentUserId}/urlCollection/${idOnNewDoc}` --> does that make sense?

Comment: Well I figured it out eventually. There were some methods in the code that set up the model and updated the firestore. That's not my code, so I'm having this difficulties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I am seeing is you are using cloud storage to save profile pictures and you want to save each one of the urls those pictures. You need to understand that both **setValue()** and **updateValue()** do just about the same thing. A note with updateValue() is it will create that document if it doesn't already exist. So, when updating values in Firestore understand that it sets the value to what you give it, which can be misleading at first.

1st When updating any document start by getting the document first. If people are constantly updating different document you may want to consider using Firestore transactions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions 
This will make sure that your data is updated correctly.

2nd Append the URL to the to the array, I am not how you set it up, but I would setup the firestore to look something like this

```
"users" = [
    "unique_id = "{
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "unique_id": "document_id_here"
        "faces": [ {key: value} ]
    }
]
```

When you serialize that object your faces object should be this **[[String: Any]]**

3rd, last step would be to get the document and update just that value

```
// Get the value in the completion with the data use this code
// Drill down to the property you want to update using the completion data ex.
var faces = completedData.faces
faces.append("[key: value]") 


// Update the data back to firestore

let path = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document("unique_user_id")

// Merging is so important. otherwise it will override your document 
path.setData(["facesKey: faces"], merge: true) {(error in
   if let error = error {
      // good error handling here
    }

    // Successfully updated document 

)}
```